# temporarily disable/toggle syntax highlighting in ace

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Is there a way to toggle syntax-highlighting in ace.js?

I know you can switch between syntax-highlighting modes with `editor.setMode()`, but what about just straight turning the syntax-highlighting off?

I can't seem to find any docs on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle it with css, let's say the class of your ACE editor is `.ace-xcode`, here you can toggle a class `monochrome` on it:

```js
function toggleSyntaxHighlighting() {
  document.querySelector('.ace-xcode').classList.toggle('monochrome');
}
```

In your css code. If the class `.monochrome` is on, disable the color of the spans by assigning this rule:

```css
.ace-xcode.monochrome span {
    color: initial !important;
}
```